# Overriding Bootstrap variables without touching Bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, bower, yo

How can I override the Bootstrap variables if I don't want to touch the Bower files?

I am using Yo, Grunt, and Bower. For yo, I am using cg-angular.

My app.less looks like this:

```
@import "bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "bower_components/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";
@fa-font-path: "bower_components/font-awesome/fonts";
....
```

Comment: Are you talking about variables.less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of including all `bootstrap.less`, copy his content to your `app.less` and import your own `variables.less` after bootsrap vars, but before modules:

```
@bootrap-dir: "bower_components/bootstrap/less";

@import "@{bootrap-dir}/variables.less";
@import "your-variables.less";
@import "@{bootrap-dir}/mixins.less";
@import "your-mixins.less";
//...
```

Later, you can load only the modules you need.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to override original bootstrap variables is to duplicate the variables.less file in your project directory and load it right after the bootstrap bower import. In the blog http://iamkevinrhodes.com/  this workaround is also mentioned in section: 5. A new approach to global theming

Answer (score 0):

[Variables in less are lazy loaded and the last definition wins](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading). So therefore just import your version of variables.less right after importing the bootstrap from npm or bower. e.g.

```
@import "bootstrap"
@import "custom/less/variables.less"
```