# Override Foundation Variables while keeping bower files clean

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, bower

I'm new to Foundation and special to SCSS. I aks my self, what the best practice is, to overwrite defaults, like colors and fontsizes.

There is a similar question for Bootstrap, which I would accept as the right answer:
[Overriding Bootstrap variables without touching Bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024537/overriding-bootstrap-variables-without-touching-bower)

How would you solve this with Foundation?

Ok, to make it more clear. I have a folder structure like this:

```
├── app
├── app.js
├── bower.json
├── bower_components
│   ├── foundation
│       ├── bower.json
│       ├── css
│       ├── js
│       ├── package.json
│       └── scss
│       ├── foundation
│       │   ├── _functions.scss
│       │   ├── _settings.scss
│       └── components
│       ├── foundation.scss
│       └── normalize.scss
├── gulpfile.js
├── index.html
├── scss
    ├── app.scss
    └── theme
        ├── _settings.scss
        └── theme.scss
```

When I change the desired variables my theme settings partials, nothing seems to happen. I just don't want touch anything from bower.
My `app.scss` file imports the bower `foundation.scss` and `theme.scss` which then loads my settings partial.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Why do you think Foundation would be any different from Bootstrap?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351726/foundation-variables-and-mixins-not-working-correctly

Comment: Show us these files: `app.scss` and `theme.scss`. Have you changed something in the `_settings.scss`?

Comment: To end this topic here and bring some enlightenment into it, I'd like to add that we run our development environment in a vagrant box.
We had to add following line in our nginx.conf to 
`sendfile off;`
You can read about more about the Problem [here](http://fsainz.com/2014/07/25/vagrant-not-updating-files.html)

Then the desired workflow worked like a charm.